# Squashing screen resolution in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, resolution

I've made a game in 1920x1080 res in XNA, and I can't seem to find a way for the graphics device to squash the screen images to other resolutions like 1600x900 when played on different computers.

How can I get my game to be in proportion, and fit on smaller screens with the same aspect ratio?

Comment: Hm...it sounds a bit like this might have been done in the wrong order. I think there may be methods of resizing involving writing the game view into a texture, and then modifying it, but even that would have performance implications. The better method is a more responsive coding architecture in which each draw call is scaled appropriately.